# Less border in one

Tags: css, less

How to write the code below in less. How to optimally shorten the code.
Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
.border {
  border: solid 1px;
}
.border-color-inherit {
  border-color: inherit !important;
}
.border-top {
  border-top: solid 1px;
}
.border-left {
  border-left: solid 1px;
}
.border-bottom {
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
}
.border-right {
  border-right: solid 1px;
}
.border-none {
  border: none !important;
}
```

I try:

```
@x: ~"solid 1px";
.res (@border) 
     {
        border-top: @x;
        border-left: @x;
        border-right: @x;
        border-bottom: @x;
  }

  .border-top{
    .res (@x);
  .border-left{
    .res (@x);  
  }
  }
```

So, I tried in many ways to make it possible but without any success.
It does not look good.

Comment: where is your HTML code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18016837/7427111

Comment: By the way, do you know you're trying (also noticeable with your other Qs here) to use CSS in totally wrong way? The purpose of CSS *is not* to generate a zillion classes for all possible class/property/value combinations for all possible use-cases. E.g. if you want to hardcode some `border-right: solid 1px;` for a HTML element - you do just that: `<div style="border-right: solid 1px">` w/o any css. `<div class="border-right">` does not make too much sense at all (there's no point in making your HTML shorter by 5 characters at cost of imposing a few megabytes css file on it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it this way

```
.border {
  border: solid 1px;
  border-color: inherit !important;
}

.border-none {
  border: none !important;
}
```